# Insert rows and columns in google chart dataTable

Tags: javascript, charts, insert, google-visualization, rows

i have proble with google charts api. I need insert columns and rows in data table preloaded chart.

When execute updateChart() i have this error: Uncaught Error: Every row given must be either null or an array.

And here is my code

```
google.load("visualization", "1", {packages:["corechart"]});
  google.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);
  function drawChart() {
    var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();

    data.addColumn('string', 'Year');
    data.addColumn('number', 'Sales');
    data.addColumn('number', 'Expenses');



    data.addRows([
    ['2004', 1000, 400],
    ['2005', 1170, 460],
    ['2006',  860, 580],
    ['2007', 1030, 540]
    ]);

    var options = {
      title: 'Company Performance'
    };

    var chart = new google.visualization.LineChart(document.getElementById('chart_div'));
    chart.draw(data, options);
  }      
  function updateChart() {

      data.insertColumn(3, 'number', 'Other');
      data.insertRows(3, [800,600,400,300])

  }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You used `data.insertRows()` so you have to use an array of arrays, for example:

```
data.insertRows(3, [['2008', 600, 400, 300]]);
```

In this case data of 2008 will be inserted in before 2007.

Comment: Great, thank you very much: 
**data.insertRows(3, [['2008', 600, 400, 300]]);**